# Created function for highchart is not taking values and showing properly

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Hi I try to create spider chart using high chart but it taking first 4 values(parm1,parm2,parm3,parm4) properly but not the other 4 values (data1,data2,data3,data4)
i am using this code to call these values `finalResults.innerHTML += spiderChart (PM,AF,AT,AD,dataPM,dataAF,dataAT,dataAD) + "<br>"` values of PM,AF,AT and AD are showing properly in spider chat but for data dataPM,dataAF,dataAT,dataAD it is showing nothing ... i check the function by replacing variable with acctual value and it was working properly... please let me know what is wrong here ?

```
function spiderChart(parm1,parm2,parm3,parm4,data1,data2,data3,data4) {

  $('#container2').highcharts({

      chart: {
          polar: true,
          type: 'line',
          margin: 0
      },

      exporting: {
          enabled: false,
          buttons: {
              enabled: false
          }
      },

      title: {
          text: '&nbsp',
          x: -80,
          useHTML: true
      },

      pane: {
          size: '70%'
      },

      xAxis: {
          categories: [parm1,parm2,parm3,parm4],
          tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
          lineWidth: 0,
          labels: {
              align: 'center',
              distance: 43
          }
      },

      yAxis: {
          gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
          lineWidth: 0,
          min: 0,
          endOnTick: true,
          showLastLabel: true,
          tickPositions: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70 , 80]
      },

      credits: {
          enabled: false
      },

      tooltip: {
          shared: true,
          headerFormat: '<span style="font-size: 12px">{point.key}:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>{point.y:,.2f}</b>',
          pointFormat: '',
          useHTML: true
      },

      legend: {
          enabled: true,
          align: 'right',
          verticalAlign: 'top',
          y: 30,
          layout: 'vertical'
      },

      series: [{
          name: 'Maturity',
          data: [data1,data2,data3,data4],
          pointPlacement: 'on',
          color: 'green',
          fillOpacity: 0.2
      }]

  });
};
```

Comment: Hi @jugal, All the provided code looks correctly, but I don't know how you call `spiderChart` function. Could you create a live example with bigger context, you can start from: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/

Comment: Thanks for reply i am able to debug the issue ... the problem is when i am passing parameter so i resolve it i am using .toFixed(2) to get persentage in data ... which is having issue so i corrected it .. and it works @ppotaczek